# Getting Number of Seconds till 'Date' only

Tags: java, android, datetime

I have been working on an application in android, where I have to get the number of seconds from epoch till date...Usually when use the following function

```
long timeInSeconds = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
```

It returns me the seconds up till the current time including Date+Time. I actually want to ignore the time part of the second and keep number of seconds till date, which will result the same timestamp for the day...Is there anyway to do so..??? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Calendar timeLessCalendar = Calendar.getInstance()
timeLessCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,0);
timeLessCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
timeLessCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
timeLessCalendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);
//now grab the seconds
long secondTillDate =  timeLessCalendar.getTime().getTime()/1000;
```

Comment: @ JigarJoshi .. Thanks for your response, I have used your technique...and it is giving me desired time on emulator but not on device...what could be the issue..??? as i have checcked date and time they set accordingly..but still on device it's not same result as on emulator...help me out please...

Comment: Try setting timezone See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#Calendar(java.util.TimeZone, java.util.Locale)

Answer (score 2):

You could create a date from a string using [DateFormat.parse()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) and then convert it to a timestamp using [Date.getTime()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29).

```
/* something like this */

Date thisMorning    =  DateFormat.parse("04/23/2012 0:00 AM, PDT");
long secSinceEpoch  =  thisMorning.getTime() / 1000;
```